# mismatch detected for 'vccorlib_lib_should_be_specified_before_msvcrt_lib_to_linker': value '1' doesn't match value '0' in msvcrtd.lib

Tags: c++, c, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a C library project for UWP. There are some C files which are calling C++ WINRT functions defined in CPP file.It is compiling successfully and generating a library file(LIB). I am compiling in Visual Studio 2015 with update 1 and target platform is 10.0.10240.0

But, I want to generate DLL instead of LIB file. Here's the changes I did to change the project so that it generates DLL instead of LIB.

Try1:
So, In the startup project, In Configuration Properties => General I change Configuration from Static Library to Dynamic Library.

And in all the project, I changed from Multi-threaded Debug(/MTd) to Multi-threaded Debug DLL(/MDd).

Try2:
Created a new project Windows Universal Project and added the all the files from the project creating LIB to this project. Still, I am getting the below errors.

Now, I am getting the errors

```
vccorlibd.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'vccorlib_lib_should_be_specified_before_msvcrt_lib_to_linker': value '1' doesn't match value '0' in msvcrtd.lib(app_appinit.obj)
vccorlibd.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2005: __crtWinrtInitType already defined in msvcrtd.lib(app_appinit.obj)
msvcrtd.lib(initializers.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Any Suggestions how to resolve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same Issue and fixed it using the linker flags:

```
/nodefaultlib:vccorlib /nodefaultlib:msvcrt vccorlib.lib msvcrt.lib
```

for debug builds you can use:

```
/nodefaultlib:vccorlibd /nodefaultlib:msvcrtd vccorlibd.lib msvcrtd.lib
```

Comment: This worked for me. To set those values in the IDE: Open the project properties and go to Linker > Input. Select Debug configuration. Prefix Additional Dependencies with "vccorlibd.lib;msvcrtd.lib;". Set Ignore Specific Default Libraries to "vccorlibd;msvcrtd". Switch to Debug config an do the same, but omit the four "d" suffixes.

Answer (score 3):

The standard /nodefaultlib did not work for me.

The following linker flags (for debug) did the trick in my case:

```
/defaultlib:'vccorlibd.lib' /defaultlib:'msvcrtd.lib'
```

Comment: Btw, this can be configured via the Visual Studio IDE at Project | Properties ... | Linker | Input | Ignore Specific Default Libraries | <Edit...> for both Configuration: Debug (as provided above) and Release (minus the d suffix).