# Project Configuration for Authoring APIs in CppWinRT Runtime Component which uses a C++/CX library

Tags: c#, uwp, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I want to setup following projects (roughly) :

- APP    : UWP C# app
- LIB    : CppWinRT project for authoring C++/WinRT API using CORE
- CORE   : C++/CX project which consumes Windows Runtime Extension (written with C++ 14 standard)

One more detail **CORE** requires *Consumes Windows Runtime Extension : YES* at project level as well as individual files which use Windows Runtime Extension

I can't convert **CORE** to C++/WinRT as it would require it to confornt to C++17 standard which will be too much effort for me.

I can keep **LIB** as *consumes Windows Runtime Extension YES/NO* both ways.

problem here is

keeping **LIB** as *consumes Windows Runtime Extension : NO* I get following error :

```
Error   LNK2005 __crtWinrtInitType already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(app_appinit.obj)  RuntimeComponent1   C:\Users\arpsingh\source\repos\WinrtApp\RuntimeComponent1\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)

Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'vccorlib_lib_should_be_specified_before_msvcrt_lib_to_linker': value '1' doesn't match value '0' in MSVCRTD.lib(app_appinit.obj) RuntimeComponent1   C:\Users\arpsingh\source\repos\WinrtApp\RuntimeComponent1\vccorlibd.lib(init.obj)
```

keeping **LIB** as *consumes Windows Runtime Extension : YES*
Any APIs written in **LIB** are not accessible in **APP**

Sample git repo for all this code
https://github.com/arpit92k/WinrtApp

Comment: Have you checked this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939913/mismatch-detected-for-vccorlib-lib-should-be-specified-before-msvcrt-lib-to-lin?

Comment: @Bite yes I did but it doesn't work for me.
As mentioned I can get all this to compile by keeping LIB as "consumes Windows Runtime Extension : YES"
but now API's written in LIB are not visible outside project.

Comment: What you're trying to do should work and there may be something wrong with the solution / project set up. I suggested you try creating a new solution with similar projects to see if it works out of the box, which would mean that you may have done something wrong in setting up the solution and projects. I also suggested that there does not seem to be any reason for the CppLib (what cx is calling CORE project) to be a C++/WinRT project and that perhaps it would be better if it were a straight Win32 C++ project.